# Getting images from facebook group album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having a problem with the Graph API / FQL and I have searched however no solution has come up.

I'm unable to retrieve photos from a group album.

I can retrieve a lot of information regarding that group album which indicates that a group album is just a regular album:

```
SELECT description, owner, photo_count, type, like_info, 
cover_pid, comment_info FROM album WHERE object_id = '1382173765340875'
{
  "data": [
    {
      "description": "10 Desafio Outros!!!", 
      "owner": 1455136613, 
      "photo_count": 8, 
      "type": "normal", 
      "like_info": {
        "can_like": true, 
        "like_count": 1, 
        "user_likes": true
      }, 
      "cover_pid": "6249764165120950711", 
      "comment_info": {
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_count": 0, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Calling "/1382086785349573" gives me the group information.

Calling "/1382086785349573/albums" gives me a list of all the albums in the group including ID, album name and even correct count.

but "albumid/photos" where album ID was retrieved from previous call returns an empty array

Also "/groupid/photos" returns an empty data[] array.

Can anyone tell me why this happens? I already removed my app from sandbox mode but still showing the same problem.

I don't understand why it can retrieve album information including items count and etc but not the photos in it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Huh, just ran into the same problem. I wanted to retrieve the photos of a public Facebook group via the Graph API, but as you mentioned, the respective edges contain no data of the actual images, unlike a page or user album for example.

Comment: Hi @Spooky , unfortunately it is not possible. I had submitted a bug report and they said it was not possible. Check the other thread related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076163/how-do-i-retrieve-photos-from-a-facebook-group-using-the-graph-api/20408959#20408959

Comment: Thank you :). Yeah, it's silly that they didn't implement it this way...